# auto-populating custom nav with all items from custom post type

Tags: php, wp-query, custom-field

I have written the following code to take all of the posts in my custom post type "products" (created with ACF) and inject them each as an `<li>` in a custom nav menu.  Everything is working except that the `orderby` clause in the query doesn't seem to work.  No matter what weight I set in the Products post the order of the posts in the menu is the same.

```
<ul class="product-menu">
              <?php
              $products = new WP_Query(
                array(
                  'post_type' => 'product',
                  'post_status' => 'publish',
                  'orderby' => array(
                    'product_weight' => 'ASC',
                    ),
                )
              );

              while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                $products->the_post();
                $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );
                echo 
                '<li>
                  <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">
                    <img src="' . $post_thumbnail_url . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '">
                  </a>
                  <span>' . get_the_title() . '
                  </span>
                </li>';
              } 
              /* Restore original Post Data */
              wp_reset_postdata();?>
              </ul>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?  I don't think it's a complicated issue, I just can't seem to see the solution myself.